# Is there a way to import HierarchicalTagsPlugin (a CommonJS module) using ESM?

Tags: node.js, express, swagger-ui

I am working with Node.js and `express-jsdoc-swagger`. I have found this plugin to use hierarchical tags: [**hierarchical-tags]**(https://github.com/kael-shipman/swagger-ui-plugins/tree/hierarchical-tags-self-hosted/packages/hierarchical-tags) but it is written as a Commonjs module. Furthermore, I have used different ways to try and import it into an ESM module, as I am using `"type": "module"` in my application.

I keep on getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
    at C:\__DEVELOPMENT\pt2-backend\node_modules\swagger-ui-plugin-hierarchical-tags\build\index.js:6:14895
    at Module.<anonymous> (C:\__DEVELOPMENT\pt2-backend\node_modules\swagger-ui-plugin-hierarchical-tags\build\index.js:6:15172)
    at Module.<anonymous> (C:\__DEVELOPMENT\pt2-backend\node_modules\swagger-ui-plugin-hierarchical-tags\build\index.js:6:15300)
    at r (C:\__DEVELOPMENT\pt2-backend\node_modules\swagger-ui-plugin-hierarchical-tags\build\index.js:1:110)
    at C:\__DEVELOPMENT\pt2-backend\node_modules\swagger-ui-plugin-hierarchical-tags\build\index.js:1:902
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\__DEVELOPMENT\pt2-backend\node_modules\swagger-ui-plugin-hierarchical-tags\build\index.js:1:912)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1043:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? I have tried things like:

```js
import pkg from "swagger-ui-plugin-hierarchical-tags";
const {HierarchicalTagsPlugin} = pkg;
```

```js
import {default as HierarchicalTagsPlugin} from "swagger-ui-plugin-hierarchical-tags";
```